# Excel Range.BorderAround(), Border is always black

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

This is the code I am using:

```
rngData.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexNone,
        System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(178, 178, 178)));
```

The border color is always black no matter what RGB value I provide.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had the same problem, couldn't find any solution on the web, MS documentation for use of this method in VSTO is a bit poor.

Anyway, probably a bit late for you seeing as you posted months ago, but my workaround was simply to not use the Range.BorderAround method and write my own!

```
    private void BorderAround(Excel.Range range, int colour)
    {
        Excel.Borders borders = range.Borders;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        borders.Color = colour;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalUp].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
        borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalDown].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
        borders = null;
    }
```

Can be invoked as per below example (Contents_Table is a NamedRange in my worksheet):

```
BorderAround(Contents_Table.Cells, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189)));
```

Hope this helps someone else out there tearing their hair out.

Comment: It can be solved very easily with the solution here below from @JAIRO

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively if you're not worried to ensure the removal of inside and diagonal lines I have successfully used:

```
range.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(153, 153, 153));
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me.   (212,212,212) looks just like default!

Answer (score 5):

```
worksheet.Cells[8, i].Borders.Color = 
    System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.Range("H1:J1").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, color:=RGB(130, 130, 130)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! In my case I have a "personal" color from previously, this was my code then: range.BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, color:=MYCOLOR

Answer (score 1):

```
range.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Comment: i am sorry to ask you but how can i get "range" object ?

Comment: I want to draw simple border from the range of A1:M30

Answer (score -1):

To change the border color you have to use either

`Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)`

with the RGB code you're interesting in, or
  `ColorIndex:=3` - to get the red color, for instance.

If you use both, `[ColorIndex:=3]` will override `[Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)]` - action visible when you try to set different colors for each, or use
 `[colorindex:=xlColorIndeAutomatic]` or with `[xlColorIndexNone]`.

Unlike in Excel formulas, in VBA you can and probably should skip parameters as they are suggested by VBA's intellisense...