# How can a border be set around multiple cells in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, border

I am working on a project that creates excel files.

I am having trouble placing a border on multiple cells to organize the excel file.

Let's say I want a border from cell B5 to B10. There shouldn't be borders between B5, B6, B7,...

Currently, I have this code:

```
workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range("B5", "B10");
workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
```

It makes the borders, however it places a border around every cell instead of one big border for all cells.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265342/excel-range-borderaround-border-is-always-black

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to individually set these

```
.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom] 
.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight]
.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft]  
.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop]
```

Comment: You could also just turn LineStyle on with;
`.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;`

Comment: @FizzBuzz - that would give you borders around every cell, which the OP didn't want...

Comment: this answer assumes a little bit  `borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;`

Comment: I think the answer by @Simon addresses this better with a single line of code.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this can help :

```
workSheet_range.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick);
```

Answer (score 5):

I did this without impacting the performance. I am taking a simple excel to format : 

**Before**

[image]

I managed to store the range as `A1:C4` in a variable dynamically in **exRange** and used the below code to give border

```
((Range)excelSheet.get_Range(exRange)).Cells.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

**After**

[image]

Comment: +1 This was the only answer that resulted in the desired result for my case, the others produces a single, horizontal, way to thick line in my case.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that sets a border around each cell:

```
xlWS.get_Range("C9", "N9").Cells.Borders.Weight = XL.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// ** - You Should do it in all Cells 

//BorderAround: Medium**

worksheet.get_Range("b5", "b5").Cells.BorderAround(Missing.Value, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 0)));

worksheet.get_Range("b6", "b6").Cells.BorderAround(Missing.Value, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 0)));

worksheet.get_Range("b10", "b10").Cells.BorderAround(Missing.Value, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, use simply  UsedRange() function

```
Excel.Range tRange = oSheet.UsedRange;
            tRange.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
            tRange.Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code puts a border around the area from (row1,col1) to (row2,col2).  Individual cells do not get a border.  The variable color is an integer color index number.  See http://www.databison.com/excel-color-palette-and-color-index-change-using-vba/ for a list of index numbers and their corresponding colors.

```
    Range cell1 = worksheet.Cells[row1,col1];
    Range cell2 = worksheet.Cells[row2,col2];
    Range range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1,cell2);
    range.BorderAround(
        Type.Missing, XlBorderWeight.xlThick, (XlColorIndex)color, Type.Missing );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.UsedRange.BorderAround(
                        Xl.XlLineStyle.xlDash,
                        Xl.XlBorderWeight.xlThick,
                        Xl.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic,
                        ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Blue));
```