# Excel Cell border using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am working on a project that creates excel files. I want to border one excel cell (just one), how can I do this ?

```
Sheet2.Cells["A15"].border = true;
```

I expect the cell to be bordred, but it's not.

Comment: This may be help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743809/how-can-a-border-be-set-around-multiple-cells-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: thnx very match , it was helpful .