# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel: How to Apply a border to ONE CELL

Tags: c#, excel, border, cell, excel-interop

I am looking to apply a border to one cell using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library.

I am running a while-loop that is search for a empty cell within a certain column, once the cell is found I want to apply a border to it.

I know there many forums on this using Ranges, but I can't use the range functionality since I do not know what cell it is being applied to exactly.

My idea was:

```
(Excel.Range)xlWS.Cells[row,1].Borders.LineStyle = (Whatever Value);
```

Any advice? (besides links to other forums, I already looked through tons of forms)?

Comment: So what is not working with your current idea?

Comment: It was more of an guess, thanks to jiverson I was able to generate the proper code to do it!

Comment: Awesome! if his answer solved your problem make sure to click the check mark to accept it so we know this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 19):

```
Excel.Range range = xlWS.UsedRange;
Excel.Range cell = range.Cells[row, column];
Excel.Borders border = cell.Borders;

border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border.Weight = 2d;
```

Hope this helps someone! Puts a thin line border around cell[row,column]!

Comment: This worked as i wanted. The only thing i changed Excel.Range cell = range.Cells;

Answer (score 15):

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = range.Cells[1][1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders border = cell.Borders;
    border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100862/1967692) for more details.

Comment: Thanks ! Using your advice I was able to generate code that does the same functionality minus the amount of code.

Answer (score 5):

To each cell in range

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range chartRange;
chartRange = workSheet.get_Range("a1", "g7");
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in chartRange.Cells)
{
    cell.BorderAround2();
}
```

To whole range

```
chartRange.BorderAround2();
```

Comment: I was searching for this, thanks Muhammad. BorderAround2() draws outline for given range

Answer (score 3):

This is based on jiverson's answer, but is much more concise for basic needs; simply create a range, get its Borders, and add a border to the bottom of the range:

```
var platypusRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[1, 3]];
. . .
Borders border = platypusRange.Borders;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

Of course, you could add a border to the top and sides, too, using xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeLeft, and xlEdgeRight.