# Programmatically create borders in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, formatting

I need to know how to create borders in excel for header in the for loop based on individual cells. Below is my code to export to excel

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
worksheet.Cells[5, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
worksheet.Cells[5, i].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
worksheet.Cells[5, i].Font.Bold = true;                    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use samples from [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel: How to Apply a border to ONE CELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751192/microsoft-office-interop-excel-how-to-apply-a-border-to-one-cell), for example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = range.Cells[1][1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders border = cell.Borders;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
border[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

Comment: thx but not working as i am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application

Comment: I updated my answer for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
 public void MarkBorder(string fromColName, string toColName)
    {
         string colName = fromColName + ":" + toColName;
         CurrentWorksheet.Range[colName].BorderAround();
    }
```

where CurrentWorksheet is defined as

```
 public Worksheet CurrentWorksheet { get; set; }
```

Comment: i tried this was not working worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[5, i], worksheet.Cells[5, i]].BorderAround();

Comment: Try like these CurrentWorksheet.Range["A1:D5"].BorderAround();. Where "A1" is the top left cell and "D5" is the bottom right cell of the border rectangle.

Comment: this working but i put number as range no working as i requires cells